# expire a static HTML file at the end of the current month

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a couple of static HTML files which are generated on the first of every month and are good till end of the same month. I'd like to `expire` them at the end of the month but don't know how to tell `nginx` to do so.

Can I use Lua or some other language to calculate that date within the config file or does that take too much computing power?

Currently I'm using this config to expire them after 7 days. What do I have to change to expire them at 23:59 o'clock at the last day of the current month?

```
location ~* \.(html|HTML)$ {
  gzip_static on;
  add_header  Cache-Control public;
  expires 7d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In lua you can simply write a function.

```
-- day is the day of the month as a number
-- file can be 1 filename or a table of several filenames
function expire(file, day, time_)
    day = day or 1 -- day's default value incase it isn't set 
    -- get the current day of the month, convert it to a number and compare it to day
    -- get the current hour and minute and compare it to time_
    if tonumber(os.date("%d")) == day and os.date("%H:%M") == time_ then
        -- see if file is a table
        if type(file) == 'table' then
            -- if it is cycle through the table for the file names
            for _, filename in pairs(file) do
                -- make sure we are dealing with a string
                if type(filename) == 'string' then
                    -- delete the file
                    os.remove(filename)
                end
            end
        else
            -- make sure file is a string
            if type(file) == 'string' then
                -- delete the file
                os.remove(file)
            end
        end
    end
end

-- calling the function
expire("somefile.txt", 31, "23:59")
```

For more on `os.date` check out https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html